# in the below given program shouldn't the variable "val" be defined? what is happening to "val" exactly?

Tags: python

```
# to find sum of all numbers stored in a list
numbers = [6, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 5, 4, 11]
sum = 0
for val in numbers:
    sum = sum+val
print("The sum is", sum)
```

My code works perfectly but I can't seem to get the logic behind it.
I'm new to coding if somebody could help me it'd be great.

Comment: `val` is defined: `for val in numbers:`. It's not clear where you got the idea otherwise.

Comment: n.b. that `sum` is a builtin function in Python that you can't use if you assign something else to it.  Try replacing `sum = 0` (and all the lines after it) with the single line `print("The sum is", sum(numbers))`.

Comment: @sagi thanks a lot

Comment: @Samwise got your point thanks a lot but I wanted to get an idea about the "for" loop

Answer (score 0):

In this case `val` takes the value of the number in `numbers` one after another. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_loop.asp for a better explanation.

Comment: thanksss! a lot ^_^